# Не получается поменять цвет определённого класса c помощью JavaScript,скажите почему?

Tags: javascript, классы, style

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="pane">
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
      <h3>Лошадь</h3>
      <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
      <h3>Осёл</h3>
      <p>Домашний осёл (лат. Equus asinus asinus), или ишак, — одомашненный подвид дикого осла (Equus asinus), сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека и по-прежнему широко в хозяйстве многих развивающихся стран.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
      <h3>Кошка</h3>
      <p>Кошка, или домашняя кошка (лат. Felis silvestris catus), — домашнее животное, одно из наиболее популярных(наряду с собакой) «животных-компаньонов». Являясь одиночным охотником на грызунов и других мелких животных, кошка — социальное животное, использующее для общения широкий диапазон звуковых сигналов.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
let button = document.body.getElementsByClassName('remove-button');
button.style.color = 'green';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя использован `document.body.getElementsByClassName`, а именно getElement**s**ByClassName, можешь использовать [forEach](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration)

Меняем [стиль](https://api.jquery.com/css/)(background color) всем элементам, [которые мы нашли](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) через *поиск* `.pane > h3`

```js
$('.pane').children('h3').css('background', 'lightgrey');
```

Тут еще можно отметить, что если нужен конкретный элемент - можно сделать [перебор](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Добавляем на страницу [стиль](http://htmlbook.ru/html/style), в котором уже прописаны стили для всех интересующих нас - элементов

```js
$('body').append(`<style>.pane > p{background: darkgreen;}</style>`);
```

```js
$('.pane').children('h3').css('background', 'lightgrey');

$('body').append(`<style>.pane > p{background: darkgreen;}</style>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="pane">
        <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
        <h3>Лошадь</h3>
        <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
        <h3>Осёл</h3>
        <p>Домашний осёл (лат. Equus asinus asinus), или ишак, — одомашненный подвид дикого осла (Equus asinus), сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека и по-прежнему широко в хозяйстве многих развивающихся стран.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
        <h3>Кошка</h3>
        <p>Кошка, или домашняя кошка (лат. Felis silvestris catus), — домашнее животное, одно из наиболее популярных(наряду с собакой) «животных-компаньонов». Являясь одиночным охотником на грызунов и других мелких животных, кошка — социальное животное, использующее для общения широкий диапазон звуковых сигналов.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```